# Modeling the charge time of an electronic device given battery optimization

Tags: computer-science, mathematical-modeling

It seems like most phones, tablets and computers have features when charging to prevent battery degradation. When this feature is activated, it seems the battery does not charge constantly, the best way I can describe it is the battery charge percentage has a similar feature to the enzyme, kinetics reaction. Would a logistical or exponential equation best approximate the charge time.